# Python command to change several strings into one string

Tags: string

I am using

trans   = { "old_word1": "new_word" }

to translate some words into other words. However, I would like to translate several words at the same time into one defining string, such as:

trans   = { "One, two, three": "Numbers" }

However that doesn't work. Is there a command that can do that in python?

Thanks!

Comment: you can just use +. "one"+"two" = "onetwo"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search a string and replace specific words with others, you probably want to use regular expressions. Something like the following:

```
import re

re.sub('(apple|pear|banana)', 'fruit', 'I would like a pear and a banana')
```

---

Original answer:

Not sure I completely understand the question, but a dictionary can map multiple different keys to the same value.

```
{
    "One": "Numbers",
    "two": "Numbers",
    "three": "Numbers",
}
```

From your starting point, you could create the above with something like:

```
new_trans = {}
for k, v in trans.items():
    for word in k.split(', '):
        new_trans[word] = v
```

Comment: I think my example was not good enough.

The idea is to replace three strings with one different string, and the three strings have to be three specific words in the same file.

So if I want to make the script do this, I can for instance apply it by replacing:

"apple", "pear", "orange"

with "fruit"

Comment: Thanks, I think the best way to illustrate this is what I have done on two words:   new_trans = {}
    new_trans[("apple", "orange")] = "Fruit"   But it works only on two words, not five. This is what was intended to do here, with five words instead.